# Pasting into SSH fails every 512 characters

Tags: ssh, terminal

I've noticed in the past that when I paste into a terminal window connected over SSH that occasionally characters get dropped from the stream. Usually I ignore the issue and search/replace them manually, but this time I investigated more.

I found out that ever 512th character doesn't make it to the server. So, if I paste the following string:

> ______________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________X______________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________X______________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________X______________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________X______________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________X

...all I see in the terminal window is a row of underscores.

This happens pretty consistently across the various servers I need to connect to - is it a problem with my terminal, the SSH setup on the servers, SSH in general or something else?

EDIT:

I'm using `OpenSSH_5.2p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8l 5 Nov 2009` on Snow Leopard, but noticed the issue on Leopard previously too

Comment: I can't reproduce this from client OS X 10.6.5 (OpenSSH_5.2p1) up against OpenBSD 4.8 running OpenSSH 5.6. Tell us more. If you cat > /dev/null and paste into your ssh session, does it also happen? Does it happen if you paste locally into an OS X terminal?

Answer (score 2):

Almost certainly your SSH client, I use putty and routinely past in more than 512 chars, I couldn't recommend it more.

Comment: Yea this is certainly a client problem, I paste hundreds of lines of code into nano through my ssh terminal all the time without problem.

Answer (score 0):

Some Operating Systems use short buffers for the pseudo-tty pipes and when they are overflooded they just drop data